# Use jQuery to (inject) addClass to an animated Javascript slider?

Tags: jquery, dom, reflection, selector, addclass

I have an image slider on my home page based off of Javascript, I pulled it from some open-source website. It works very well for what I need it to do. However, I want to add a reflection below the images using the [reflection.js](http://www.digitalia.be/software/reflectionjs-for-jquery) script. To insert the reflection I need to add the class of "reflect" to my img elements. And to do that I need to use an external .js file to add the class to the images in the carousel.

What I have so far is: `$('div.skin-default img').addClass("reflect");` but I think that it is only trying to add this on DOM load. Because the images are being switched out (only 2 pre-load at any given time) dynamically, the class is not added to the other images in the carosel on the time the DOM loaded. Is that the issue here? And if so how can I tell jQuery to keep checking for new image elements and automatically add the class "reflect"? I am still quite a bit new to jQuery.

Also, I am using Drupal 7 as my website and Galleria as the image slider plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Patch `$('div.skin-default img').addClass("reflect");` into the slider script after the new elements are appended, either as a callback (if the script is configured to accept a callback) or procedurally (on the following line).

Alternatively, you could hook into the DOM mutation event that's triggered by the append. Have a look at [this](https://github.com/jollytoad/jquery.mutation-events) plugin if you need to support legacy browsers.

Comment: I understand what you're saying, but based on my inexperience, I can't find the insertion point for the patch. Here is the Javascript code for the theme: http://jsfiddle.net/nXrj2/

Comment: Try adding your snippet after `c.$("thumbs").removeClass("active")`.

Comment: If I add my snippet as is Chrome's console returns an error "Uncaught TypeError: Property '$' of object [object Window] is not a function" Here is the JSfiddle with the snippet added: http://jsfiddle.net/nXrj2/3/

Comment: So what your saying is that there is no possible way to do this, even by injecting the class through another file?

Comment: I'm not saying that at all... as long as you call your snippet after the new elements have been appended to the DOM, it *should* work.